# What is the hardness, hit points and saving throw mod for a mithral shirt +1?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, armor

Pretty simple question:

What is the hardness, hit points and saving throw mod for a mithral shirt +1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TL;DR

Hp 25, Hardness 15, Saving throws +3 or those of the wearer, if they are higher.

## The full breakdown

We actually have to go over quite a few sources to collect the answer to this "simple" question, but here we go:

First up, the Hit points of a set of armor are found on the [SRD here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm#tableCommonArmorWeaponAndShieldHardnessAndHitPoints):

An armor's hit points is equal to its armor bonus x 5, so that means a +1 Mithral Chain Shirt has 25 hp for its +5 armor bonus. But it says the Hardness is "special; varies by material".

So next step, we need to look up Mithral under [special materials](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialMaterials.htm) and find out its hardness. From the special materials page, we find that the hardness of Mithral is 15.

And finally, the saving throw bonus. Looking at [this page](http://dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#breaking-and-entering) we can find the section about magic item saving throws:

> Magic items always get saving throws. A magic item’s Fortitude, Reflex, and Will save bonuses are equal to 2 + one-half its caster level. An attended magic item either makes saving throws as its owner or uses its own saving throw bonus, whichever is better.

That means we need the creator's caster level... let's assume minimum level. If you happen to *know* who made the item, you can use their caster level instead.

Now, the minimum caster level to create armor is found [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingMagicArmor), and it turns out to be 3 x enhancement bonus. So we'll assume a level 3 crafter.

So with that, we can determine the total saving throw bonus, which is (2 + 1/2 * 3), which comes to +3. Or whatever the wearer's bonus is, should it be higher.

I figured it'd be a simple question as well, but it turns out the information is quite spread out. Hopefully this'll help you figure it out for other items in the future as well.

Comment: There's actually one more scattered bit that's often relevant-- magic weapons and shields [get bonus hp and hardness](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm), but that happens not to apply here, because for whatever reason there's no equivalent rule for armor.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like questions like this should be much simpler to research.